# How to get the value of the ref attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to get the value `wwww` of the `ref` attribute?

```
<form @submit.prevent enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" ref="wwww" @change="selectFile">
</form>
```

I do like this:

```
console.log(this.$refs.wwww)
```

But instead of a value, I get like this:

```
<input type="file">
```

I need it like this: `wwww`

Comment: It's unclear what you ask about. You already have the name when you do `console.log(this.$refs.wwww)` because you know it and can type it . This could be XY problem.

Answer (score 2):

The point of refs is precisely to get a reference to a DOM element. If you're trying to save arbitrary data on your element and access it via JavaScript, I'd recommend using data attributes:

```
<input type="file" ref="inputElement" data-whatever="wwww">
```

Then access it like so:

```
const { inputElement } = this.$refs;
console.log(inputElement.dataset.whatever); // "wwww"
```

See also [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and [Template refs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html).